# Cloud Storage of Protected Images and Fast Access

Tags: image, amazon-s3

Writing an application for a client that is very photo focused.  Users will be uploading hundreds of images to their account.  These images are only accessible to the owners.  Our first thought was to throw them all out on AmazonS3 but after doing some research we have found that accessing protected files on S3 is too slow for the kind of response we need.  Also, from further research, we're not sure that non-US users are going to have a good experience because of S3 (still researching that one).

I'm wondering if I'm finding the right information or not.  Is it possible to host images on S3 that have specific user rights and are pulled down quickly?  Would we need to implement some sort of caching proxy to speed things up?  Should I be looking at hosting the images on our own servers and delivering them that way?  Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the CloudFront CDN in front of S3? That might be why it's a bit slow.

If you don't like Amazon, you could use [CloudFiles](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/files) from Rackspacecloud. That uses Limelight as a CDN.